# CloudKit modifySubscriptionCompletionBlock

Tags: ios, swift, closures

i try to make a subscription with CloudKitOperations but getting the following error:

[image: failure in XCode]

What am I doing wrong?

```
let subscriptionOperation = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: subscriptionsToUpload, subscriptionIDsToDelete: nil)
    subscriptionOperation.database = _publicDB

    subscriptionOperation.modifySubscriptionsCompletionBlock { (modifiedSubscriptions: [CKSubscription]?, deletedSubscriptionIDs: [String]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        guard operationError==nil else {
            // handle Error
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                let title:String = "Alert_CloudKit_Subscription_Error_Title".localized
                let message:String = err.localizedDescription
                self._animationDelegate?.endAnimation()
                self._alertDelegate?.showAlert(title, message: message)
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("switchSubscribeToNewRecordOff", object: nil)
            })
            return
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            print("CloudKit subscription success")

            let title:String = "Alert_CloudKit_Subscription_Success_Title".localized
            let message:String = "Alert_CloudKit_Subscription_Success_Messagen".localized + " \(predicate)"
            self._animationDelegate?.endAnimation()
            self._alertDelegate?.showAlert(title, message: message)
        })
    }
```

Comment: Now it works can't see any difference subscriptionOperation.modifySubscriptionsCompletionBlock = {
            (modifiedSubscriptions: [CKSubscription]?, deletedSubscriptionIDs: [String]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 wants Error? not NSError? as the type.

```
subscriptionOperation.modifySubscriptionsCompletionBlock =  {(modifiedSubscriptions: [CKSubscription]?, deletedSubscriptionIDs: [String]?, saveError: Error?) -> Void in
```